# read xml file from given tag

Tags: python, xml, boto3

How can I read xml from a given tag "Nature" in my case. My code below read the entire xml file.

```
import boto3
Read the xml file from bucket data1 of s3 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('data1', 'file12.xml')
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

Who can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@salsa I don't know exactly what do you want. My understanding is you have one XML file and you are trying to get/filter some info from that.

Here my code to get info from an XML file

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
xmlTree = parse("note.xml")
for element in xmlTree.findall("department"):
    print(element.text)

for element in xmlTree.findall("firstName"):
    print(element.text)
```

Sample XML format I used is

```
<Emp>
    <firstName>Rahul</firstName>
    <lastName>Anand</lastName>
    <dob>20/10/1990</dob>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <department>Finance</department>
    <department>Admin</department>
</Emp>
```

Result of Python code is

```
Finance
Admin
Rahul
```

Please refer my [link](https://repl.it/@TamilselvanLaks/readXML) as well https://repl.it/@TamilselvanLaks/readXML

```
Note: You should click 'run' button to execute the program.
```

Please let me know is this meet your expectation.

Comment: Yes thank you so much . I have to verify some values of fiels, so parsing, creating new tags if needed. xml.etree.ElementTree is the best library do yo think?

Comment: i want for example to rename the tag <gender> to <gn>. So my new xml file will be <Emp>
    <firstName>Rahul</firstName>
    <lastName>Anand</lastName>
    <dob>20/10/1990</dob>
    <gn>Male</gn>
    <department>Finance</department>
    <department>Admin</department>
</Emp>

Comment: So you want to modify the file? but in your question, you mentioned you want to read the file only.

Comment: its easier for me to create a new file with the modification. I think

Comment: ok if my answer helpful to you please mark it as 'This answer is useful'